# 'NoneType' object is not iterable error in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, typeerror

I am trying to write a code that takes my input as a command(TEAM),(given name of the team) and then returns to the number of player who are playing in the team that is given in the input.But pycharm gives a'NoneType' object is not iterable error and I do not know how can I turn it into code that workes.Can you help me find where I went wrong?
By the way,I assume that there are mistakes even in the way of asking this question, if you share it with me, I will try to improve myself, thanks in advance !!

baseball_stats = [['Martin,Leonys', 'TEX', 147, 457, 66, 119, 21, 6, 8], ['Smoak,Justin', 'SEA', 131, 454, 53, 108, 19, 0, 20], ['Ibanez,Raul', 'SEA', 124, 454, 54, 110, 20, 2, 29], ['Infante,Omar', 'DET', 118, 453, 54, 144, 24, 3, 10], ['Bautista,Jose', 'TOR', 118, 452, 82, 117, 24, 0, 28], ['Blanco,Gregor', 'SF', 141, 452, 50, 120, 17, 6, 3], ['Rosario,Wilin', 'COL', 121, 449, 63, 131, 22, 1, 21], ['Uggla,Dan', 'ATL', 136, 448, 60, 80, 10, 3, 22],
['Moss,Brandon', 'OAK', 145, 446, 73, 114, 23, 3, 30], ['Tulowitzki,Troy', 'COL', 126, 446, 72, 139, 27, 0, 25], ['Mauer,Joe', 'MIN', 113, 445, 62, 144, 35, 0, 11], ['Overbay,Lyle', 'NYY', 142, 445, 43, 107, 24, 1, 14], ['Pollock,A.J.', 'ARI', 137, 443, 64, 119, 28, 5, 8], ['Drew,Stephen', 'BOS', 124, 442, 57, 112, 29, 8, 13], ['Viciedo,Dayan', 'CWS', 124, 441, 43, 117, 23, 3, 14], ['Dirks,Andy', 'DET', 131, 438, 60, 112, 16, 2, 9],

```
command, name = input().split()
def baseball_stat_machine(command, name):
  command=input()
  if command=="TEAM":
     name=input()
     for ply in baseball_stats:
          if name==ply[1]:
          result=baseball_stats.count(ply[0]
result = baseball_stat_machine(command, name)

if type(result) == int:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Please show the exact and complete error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

You must first enter the Information then call the function and finally print the result, if a player is found

like so

```
baseball_stats = [['Martin,Leonys', 'TEX', 147, 457, 66, 119, 21, 6, 8], ['Smoak,Justin', 'SEA', 131, 454, 53, 108, 19, 0, 20], ['Ibanez,Raul', 'SEA', 124, 454, 54, 110, 20, 2, 29], ['Infante,Omar', 'DET', 118, 453, 54, 144, 24, 3, 10], ['Bautista,Jose', 'TOR', 118, 452, 82, 117, 24, 0, 28], ['Blanco,Gregor', 'SF', 141, 452, 50, 120, 17, 6, 3], ['Rosario,Wilin', 'COL', 121, 449, 63, 131, 22, 1, 21], ['Uggla,Dan', 'ATL', 136, 448, 60, 80, 10, 3, 22], ['Moss,Brandon', 'OAK', 145, 446, 73, 114, 23, 3, 30], ['Tulowitzki,Troy', 'COL', 126, 446, 72, 139, 27, 0, 25], ['Mauer,Joe', 'MIN', 113, 445, 62, 144, 35, 0, 11], ['Overbay,Lyle', 'NYY', 142, 445, 43, 107, 24, 1, 14], ['Pollock,A.J.', 'ARI', 137, 443, 64, 119, 28, 5, 8], ['Drew,Stephen', 'BOS', 124, 442, 57, 112, 29, 8, 13], ['Viciedo,Dayan', 'CWS', 124, 441, 43, 117, 23, 3, 14], ['Dirks,Andy', 'DET', 131, 438, 60, 112, 16, 2, 9]]

def baseball_stat_machine(command, name):

  if command=="TEAM":

     for ply in baseball_stats:
          if name==ply[0]:
            result=baseball_stats.count(ply[0])
            return result
command=input("Enter command form example TEAM: ")
name=input("ENter a name: ")
result = baseball_stat_machine(command, name)
if type(result) == int:
    print(result)
```

This will count the TEAM you enter for SEA is two times there

```
baseball_stats = [['Martin,Leonys', 'TEX', 147, 457, 66, 119, 21, 6, 8], ['Smoak,Justin', 'SEA', 131, 454, 53, 108, 19, 0, 20], ['Ibanez,Raul', 'SEA', 124, 454, 54, 110, 20, 2, 29], ['Infante,Omar', 'DET', 118, 453, 54, 144, 24, 3, 10], ['Bautista,Jose', 'TOR', 118, 452, 82, 117, 24, 0, 28], ['Blanco,Gregor', 'SF', 141, 452, 50, 120, 17, 6, 3], ['Rosario,Wilin', 'COL', 121, 449, 63, 131, 22, 1, 21], ['Uggla,Dan', 'ATL', 136, 448, 60, 80, 10, 3, 22], ['Moss,Brandon', 'OAK', 145, 446, 73, 114, 23, 3, 30], ['Tulowitzki,Troy', 'COL', 126, 446, 72, 139, 27, 0, 25], ['Mauer,Joe', 'MIN', 113, 445, 62, 144, 35, 0, 11], ['Overbay,Lyle', 'NYY', 142, 445, 43, 107, 24, 1, 14], ['Pollock,A.J.', 'ARI', 137, 443, 64, 119, 28, 5, 8], ['Drew,Stephen', 'BOS', 124, 442, 57, 112, 29, 8, 13], ['Viciedo,Dayan', 'CWS', 124, 441, 43, 117, 23, 3, 14], ['Dirks,Andy', 'DET', 131, 438, 60, 112, 16, 2, 9]]

def baseball_stat_machine(command, name):

  if command=="TEAM":
    result=sum(ply[1].count(name) for ply in baseball_stats)  
    return result
   
command=input("Enter command form example TEAM: ")
name=input("ENter a name: ")
result = baseball_stat_machine(command, name)
if type(result) == int:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have tried this one but it does not work.Maybemaybe i should explain better. I want to give an input like command,( which is TEAM) and the name of a random team then return to the number of player who plays in the given team.This is why I wrote  if name==ply[0]:
            result=baseball_stats.count(ply[0]) but it does not work either.I would appreciate your help and thanks for your help so far, it opened my mind

Comment: i added a count of team, the principle is the same, only the syntax changes, and you will find if you search for it many helpful hints